# Array Explode values in single database table with 3 different rows print in a table how?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, explode, mysqlimport

In my database, I have one table with a number of rows are there some rows of data saved as comma-separated and some rows are saved without comma separated.

My problem is explode the values some empty values are also view how to stop that values.

Source code looks like this

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered">
                 <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th>Sl.No</th>
                       <th>Item Name </th>
                       <th>Category</th>
                       <th>Brand</th>
                       <th>Qty</th>
                       <th>Unit Price</th>
                       <th>Amount</th>
                       <th>Pic</th>
                       <th>Others</th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                    <?php
                    require_once("../dbconfig.php");
                    extract($_REQUEST);
                    
                    $sql="SELECT * FROM `purchase_data` where project_id='$proid'";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    $count=$result->num_rows;
                    if ($count > 0) {
                    $x=1;
                    while ($pur_row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                           $proid =$pur_row['pur_id']; 

                            $category = $pur_row['pur_category'];
                            $categories = explode(',',$category);
                            $lenght = count($categories);

                            print_r($categories);

                            $product = $pur_row['pur_itemname'];
                            $products = explode(',',$product);

                            $brand = $pur_row['pur_brand'];
                            $brands = explode(',',$brand);

                            $unitprice = $pur_row['pur_rate'];
                            $unitprices = explode(',',$unitprice);

                            $qty = $pur_row['pur_qty'];
                            $quantity = explode(',',$qty);

                            $remarks = $pur_row['pur_others'];
                            $remark = explode(',',$remarks);

                            $est_amou = $pur_row['pur_amount'];
                            $est_amount = explode(',',$est_amou);

                            $edr_others = $pur_row['pur_others'];
                            $edr_other = explode(',',$edr_others);
                             ?>
                             <?php for($i=0; $i<=$lenght; $i++)
                                {  ?>
                    <tr>
                       <td><?=$x;?></td>
                       <td><?=$products[$i];?></td>
                       <td><?=$categories[$i];?></td>
                       <td><?=$brands[$i];?></td>
                       <td><?=$quantity[$i];?></td>
                       <td><?=$unitprices[$i];?></td>
                       <td><?=$est_amount[$i];?></td>
                       <td></td>
                       <td><?=$edr_other[$i];?></td>
                    </tr>
                   <?php $x++;  }  } }  ?>
                 </tbody>
             </table>
```

Here I will share my screenshots of the database and front view

[image: database look like this]

[image: front end look lie this]

remove white spaces and continue values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your `for` loop, `$lenght` is the number of categories, but you are looping from 0 to `$lenght` instead of 0 to `$lenght-1` which is resulting in the blank rows. Change your `for` statement to:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i < $lenght; $i++)
```

Comment: i will change like <?php for($i=$lenght-1; $i<=$lenght; $i++) but blank is came and remain two fields are empty

Comment: @NagendraKumar change it to what I wrote in the answer. Note that `<=` has changed to `<`

Comment: i will change what can u wrote  above  i will change

Comment: here i have 5 values are there but display only 3 values once see my database   cement two times and BMData,qwert,asdds but i have only print cement,qwertd,sdsdsd

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php for($i=0; $i< $lenght; $i++) i will change thar <= replace to < then output will came
```

{  ?>

do something

} ?>